# Как с vue js формы сохранять данные в json формате?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuex

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: 'cart',
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  methods: {
    sendForm() {
    //?????
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

```css
form {
    flex-basis: 30%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 #e0e0e0;
    height: 330px;
}
.form__wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.form__wrap input {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.form__wrap input[type="submit"] {
      border: none;
      transition: 0.3s;
      padding: 15px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<form 
 action=""
 @submit="sendForm"
>
  <div class="form__wrap">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Phone">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. на поля формы вешаете `v-model` как свойства объекта `form` из `data`;
2. в `action` для `HTML` `<form>` прописываете URL сервера, который будет принимать ваш `JSON`;
3. используя обычный `fetch` вы можете отправить ваш `JSON` приведенным ниже способом.

*В примере используется `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts` как адрес сервера, необходимо изменить на ваш URL*

Больше о fetch по [ссылке](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      form: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sendForm(e) {

      // отменяем действие по умолчанию для кнопки Send 
      e.preventDefault()
      console.log('Отправка JSON данных', this.form)

      // используя fetch формируем запрос
      fetch(
        // URL куда будем отправлять запрос
        e.target.action,
        // параметры запроса
        {
          method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
          mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
          cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
          credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(this.form) // тип данных, должен соответствовать "Content-Type"
        }
      ).then(
        function(response) {
          // успешно получен ответ сервера на запрос
          console.log('Ответ сервера', response);
        },
        function(error) {
          // Ошибка при осуществлении запроса
          console.error(error);
        }
      );

    }
  },
})
```

```css
form {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 #e0e0e0;
  height: 330px;
}

.form__wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.form__wrap input {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.form__wrap input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding: 15px;
}


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <form action="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts" @submit="sendForm">
    <div class="form__wrap">
      <input type="text" v-model="form.name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
      <input type="text" v-model="form.surname" name="surname" placeholder="Phone">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает. Как можно сохранить не на сервер а в файл?

Comment: если вы имеете ввиду на клиенте - прочтите вот этот ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48611671/vue-js-write-json-object-to-local-file